# How can you setup a flutter rawkeyboardlistener to read {} (curly brackets) instead of square brackets?

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter solution that interprets a QR code via a scanning device. I use the RawKeyboardListener to read the scanned QR code that then parses it into a variable.

The QR value is an object {something: somethingelse}, but when read by the RawKeyboardListener, it reads the {} as [] and as a result, the object is then invalid.

```
          String runtime = event.runtimeType.toString();

          if (event.data.logicalKey != LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
            setState(() {
              scannedItem += runtime == 'RawKeyUpEvent' ? event.data.keyLabel : '';
            });
          } else if (scannedItem != '') {
            setState(() {
                var data = json.decode(scannedItem);
            });
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with the solution and ended up fixing it, though I do feel there is a better way of resolving this

```
                            if (event.data.isShiftPressed) {
                              switch (event.data.logicalKey.debugName) {
                                case 'Bracket Left':
                                  keyLabel = '{';
                                  break;
                                case 'Bracket Right':
                                  keyLabel = '}';
                                  break;
                                case 'Quote':
                                  keyLabel = '"';
                                  break;
                                case 'Semicolon':
                                  keyLabel = ':';
                                  break;
                                default:
                                  keyLabel = keyLabel.toUpperCase();
                                  break;
                              }
                            }
```